# JS - querySelector returns an illegal or invalid string error - but valid string for class name in console.log

Tags: javascript

I have the below code:

```
var parentdepth=depth-1;
var parentclass=classes[parentdepth];
console.log(parentclass); // prints 0-check
//el=e.querySelector('.'+parentclass);
```

`console.log(parentclass);` has no problem and prints the parent class name, but when I command the `el=e.querySelector('.'+parentclass);`, below error appears:

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified
```

Note that `console.log(e)` is `<section class="to y-12 y-3 0-check">`.

Also, note that my goal is to append a child inside the class which matches `0-check` in its name.

Comment: `".0-check"` is not a valid css selector; you could use `"[class~='0-check']"` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class name starts with a digit, and the CSS parser doesn't like that digit starting the class name in the selector string. You *can* use such a class name, but you'll need to express it differently, specifically as the JavaScript string `"\\40-class"`. That'll result in the CSS selector parser seeing `.\40-class`, and that will not cause an error. It will correctly match an element like

```
<span class=0-check>Hello World</span>
```

It's interesting to note that the HTML markup itself will not cause an error, because the HTML parser doesn't care what the attribute value looks like.

From your question, it seems that you might be trying to test whether an element matches the selector. If so, then `.querySelector()` is not the API to use anyway; you want `.matches()` (which in older browsers was prefixed and called "matchesSelector"). So,

```
var matches = e.matches("." + parentclass);
```

That function returns a boolean.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I changed the name to `check-0` and it works fine. But, `console.log(el)` returns `null`, any idea?

Comment: @Sami well, what does the HTML look like? Is there really an element with class "check-0"?

Comment: Ah well if you're calling `.querySelector()` from an element, the browser is going to only look for **descendant** elements with that class name.

Comment: The html is `<section class="ro s-12 m-3 check-0"></section>`, and I want to append another element inside that `el.appendChild(z.t);`

Comment: @Sami I just updated the answer. You can use `.matches()` instead of `.querySelector()` if you want to check whether an element matches a particular selector.

Comment: I used `matchesSelector`, but the firebug gives the error `TypeError: e.matchesSelector is not a function`.

Comment: @Sami in modern Firefox it's just `.matches()`; same in most new browser versions.

Comment: @Sami oh I just saw that I typed it incorrectly in the answer. Fixed now.

Comment: I think matches has the same syntax restrctions than querySelector though

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and help. My goal is to append an element inside the element which matches `check-0` in the class name, still not successful though with `el.appendChild(z.t);`, would you suggest a solution?

Comment: @Kaiido yes definitely - the class name would have to be similarly "quoted" in the selector syntax.

Comment: @Sami well if you get beyond the CSS selector syntax issue, it would be better to post a new question; I really am not sure I understand the problem. Be sure and post enough code for people reading the question to understand what you're doing (for example, what is `z.t`?).